# Change series to vertical in highchart.line

Tags: highcharts, data-visualization, linechart, axis-labels

I'm trying to render my data to highchart. I see the line chart demo like this [image: Line chart demo]

How can I change the month category to the temperature series (make it vertical) like this [image: Line chart]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I use this highchart [https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com](https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com)

Comment: Set the inverted parameter: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.inverted